# Is there a way to change this loop into an array/range reference?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I'm trying to move total balances associated with unique ID combinations to another sheet using dictionaries. The loop may have to run on tens of thousands of rows and even at 900 rows the process takes around 30 seconds.

I've got my code working with (multiple) dictionaries and loops, but it's quite slow. I was wondering if there's a way to optimize the loop (possibly through using arrays? Though I'm very inexperienced with them).

I tried to setup an array loop for I=lbound to ubound but I was nowhere close to getting it working (code was a mess). Below is a snippet of code and one of the loops I am trying to optimize. There are 4 other loops later on but for now I just want to optimize the one.

```
'declare start/end rows
Dim StartRowPeriod As Long
    StartRowPeriod = 7
Dim LastRowPeriod As Long
    LastRowPeriod = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'more dims for total bal
Dim HardCopyID As String
Dim Old_Balance As Double
Dim New_Balance As Double
Dim Updated_Balance As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'RUNNING THE DICTIONARY (ADDING THE TOTAL VALUES TO THE UNIQUE IDS)
For I = StartRowPeriod To LastRowPeriod
    HardCopyID = Cells(I, 11).Value
        If HardCopyID = "" Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf HardCopy_Dictionary.Exists(HardCopyID) Then
            Old_Balance = HardCopy_Dictionary(HardCopyID)
            New_Balance = Cells(I, 10).Value
            Updated_Balance = Old_Balance + New_Balance
            HardCopy_Dictionary(HardCopyID) = Updated_Balance
        Else
            HardCopy_Dictionary(HardCopyID) = Cells(I, 10).Value
        End If
Next I
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, switching to a Variant Array approach will speed this up enormously.

You code, refactored to use Array, plus a few other cleanups:

```
Sub Demo()
    ' declare all variables
    Dim i As Long
    Dim HardCopy_Dictionary As Dictionary ' early bound: set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    'Dim HardCopy_Dictionary As Object ' late bound
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Dat As Variant

    'declare start/end rows
    Dim StartRowPeriod As Long
    Dim LastRowPeriod As Long

    'more dims for total bal
    Dim HardCopyID As String
    Dim Old_Balance As Double
    Dim New_Balance As Double
    Dim Updated_Balance As Double

    ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'not needed as there is no sheet interaction

    Set HardCopy_Dictionary = New Dictionary ' Early bound
    'Set HardCopy_Dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  ' Late bound

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    StartRowPeriod = 7
    With ws
        LastRowPeriod = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Copy data to array
        Dat = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRowPeriod, 11)).Value
        'RUNNING THE DICTIONARY (ADDING THE TOTAL VALUES TO THE UNIQUE IDS)
        For i = StartRowPeriod To LastRowPeriod
            HardCopyID = Dat(i, 11) '.Cells(i, 11).Value
            If HardCopyID = vbNullString Then
                Exit For 'are you sure about this? Surley it should run to the end of the data?
            ElseIf HardCopy_Dictionary.Exists(HardCopyID) Then
                Old_Balance = HardCopy_Dictionary(HardCopyID)
                New_Balance = Dat(i, 10) '.Cells(i, 10).Value
                Updated_Balance = Old_Balance + New_Balance
                HardCopy_Dictionary(HardCopyID) = Updated_Balance
            Else
                HardCopy_Dictionary.Add HardCopyID, Dat(i, 10) '.Cells(i, 10).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This runs on some mockup data of 100,000 rows pretty much instantly.

Comment: Sorry posted nearly the same nearly the same time - shall I remove my answer?

Comment: @T.M. no big deal, that happens sometimes.  Up to you, delete or leave as you wish

Comment: Anyway +1, consider both answers as helpful :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I'll try this out when I get a chance! Hopefully I can figure out how to make the other 4 or 5 loops I have that are doing similar things into arrays based on this info! As for the "Exit For" and "ScreenUpdating", I pasted the most bare-bones possible code since I knew functionally it worked as intended (so I removed a msgbox and a bunch of other lines, hence no dictionary early bind shown).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up; this one worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Recipe**

1. Use a *fully qualified* **range reference**, otherwise you are referring to the *active sheet* by default.
2. Looping through a range via VBA is always time consuming, so use an array. 
   Suggest to refer to your worksheet's *codename* (see VB Editor), eg. `Sheet1` and
   assign the data range to a *variant 2-dimensioned 1-based* **array** as follows:

   ```
   Dim myArray     ' As Variant 
   MyArray = Sheet1.Range("A1:K" & Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
   ```
3. Simply refer to `MyArray` instead of `Cells(...)` or `Sheet1.cells(...)` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(...)` thus writing

   ```
   HardCopyID = myArray(I, 11).Value                      ' instead of HardCopyID = Cells(I, 11).Value
   New_Balance = myArray(I, 10).Value                     ' instead of New_Balance = Cells(I, 10).Value
   HardCopy_Dictionary(HardCopyID) = myArray(I, 10).Value ' instead of HardCopy_Dictionary(HardCopyID) = Cells(I, 10).Value
   ```

   (I assume you haven't forgotten to use `Option Explicit` in the declaration head of your code module to 
   force the explicit declaration of *all* variables in this module, e.g. `Dim i As Long`)

Good luck :-)

Comment: I actually have not declared option explicit, I usually just use Dim I as Long, J as Long etc. (I also only put in the relevant lines, everything works and is defined/dict is bound just above the relevant code lines). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Don't *without*, it's not only good use, but it allows you to be strict in your naming and data type conventions in order to catch mismatch errors directly in the VBA editor.